# how to store output of a command into array with each value in a double quote

Tags: shell-script, quoting, filenames, locate

I want to store each output in double quoted array values. values can have space also.

```
FOUNDFILES=($(locate --database ~/.locate.db -i -b "$INPUT"))
```

if input to the locate command is very very latest (where very very latest is the file name). it should be stored as "very very latest". Locate also locates other files with word very in them. so if there is some other file like heisvery, it should also get stored like "heisvery", where "very very latest" is the 0th value and "heisvery" is value 1 of the array.

Comment: Why? The quotes won't help you. Quoted quotes *suck*.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a rare situation indeed where you actually need to 
store a string (in a variable) along with leading and trailing 
quotation marks which aren't part of the data. It is typically 
better to post-process.

```
var='two  spaces'
printf '# "%s"\n'  "$var"
# "two  spaces"

ary=( 'two  spaces' '$USER' ) 
printf '# "%s"\n'  "${ary[@]}"
# "two  spaces"
# "$USER"
```

As `locate` outputs *fully qualified paths*,
and the `-b` option means search in only the **b**asename,
and you want *only* the basename to be captured,
then you can use `sed` to strip away the `/pa/th/` portion.

As you want to search for  "very very latest" as the *full* basename,
and you also want to search for "very" *anywhere* in basename,
then you really need to use a *regular expression* search.

- `-r`      Search for a basic regexp
- `--regex` Search for a extended regexp *(used in example below)*

To cause your array to capture entire lines, you need to change the **I**​nternal **F**​ield **S**​eparator (IFS) to `\n` only.

Note that array items are captured/stored as they are encountered in *locate's* output. To arrange them into the same order as the `input` array, some further processing of the array is needed (via *for..grep..loop..awk* below).

```
input=( '^very very latest$' 'very' )
IFS=$'\n'; foundfiles=($(locate -i -b --regex "${input[@]}" | sed 's|.*/||'))
foundfiles=($(for((i=0;i<${#input[@]};i++))
              do printf '%s\n' "${foundfiles[@]}" | grep -E "${input[i]}"
              done | awk '!seen[$0]++'))
printf '%s\n' "${foundfiles[@]}"
```

---

output - shows the full array, which is index [0] and [1]:

```
very very latest
heisvery
```

If you want the *printf* output in quotes, just change the last line to
   `printf '"%s"\n' "${foundfiles[@]}"`

...or if you still need to add the quotes into the array itself, add the following two lines after the `for..grep..loop`

```
foundfiles=("${foundfiles[@]/#/\"}")
foundfiles=("${foundfiles[@]/%/\"}")
```

output - shows the full array, which is index [0] and [1]:

```
"very very latest"
"heisvery"
```

Comment: still cant do it with my script :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want the quotes. I think you just don't want to split into fields on whitespace that isn't newlines.

Here's how to do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393817/bash-read-lines-in-file-into-an-array

And here's an example

```
$ IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a FOUNDFILES < <(echo -e "very very latest\nsome other line")
$ echo "${FOUNDFILES[0]}" 
 very very latest
$ echo "${FOUNDFILES[1]}" 
 some other line
```

`<(echo -e "very very latest\nsome other line")` would really be your `locate` command.